# Create Pandas column displaying the max number of repeated pairs from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns with lists of equal lengths, but the length of both lists may differ per row. I want to create col 3 which is the number corresponding to the max number of duplicates created by pairing the numbers by index between col 1 and col 2. For example:

```
df=

col 1                       col 2               col 3
["c","c"]                   ["d", "d"]          2 // ("c","d") is repeated twice
["a","b","c","a"]           ["f","e","e","f"]   2 //("a","f") is repeated twice while ("b","e") and ("c","e") are only repeated once
["a","b","g"]               ["f","e","f"]       1 //("a","f"), ("b","e"), and ("g","f") are repeated once
```

What I've tried so far:

My approach thus far has been to first create a new column with a list of tuples. Taking the first row in my example, I wanted to create [("c","d"), ("c","d")] and repeat this for every column. Then I planned to apply `Counter(df["col 3"]).most_common(1)[0][1]` to get the max number of duplicated pairs.

To create the column with lists of tuples I tried:
`df["col 3"] = list(zip(df["col 1"],df["col 2"]))` but this seems to return (["c","c"],["d","d"]) using the first row as an example instead of [("c","d"),("c","d")]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apply` with `Counter`:

```
df['col 3'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.max(Counter(zip(x['a'], x['b'])).values()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with a list comprehension and numpy :

```
df['col3'] = [np.max(np.unique(tuple(zip(*entry)), 
                     axis=0, 
                     return_counts=True)[-1])
             for entry in zip(df.col1, df.col2)
              ]
```